# How to specify AWS SQS request timeout with C++ API?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm using AWS SQS and making a GetQueueURL request at startup. The problem is that if there is no network connection, the request blocks and doesn't time out until more than 400 seconds have passed (using default ClientConfiguration parameters).

The only timeout parameters I can see in [ClientConfiguration](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/struct_aws_1_1_client_1_1_client_configuration.html) are:

1. httpRequestTimeoutMs
2. requestTimeoutMs
3. connectTimeoutMs

However, changing these seem to have no effect in the case I mentioned above. I tried setting all three to 1000ms and, without a network connection, the GetQueueUrl request still blocks for several minutes until it times out.

If it helps, when the timeout does occur, the error I get on the request is: `curlCode: 28, Timeout was reached`

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: GetQueueUrl's output is as consistent as its input.  So don't bother configuring with Queue Name and calling GetQueueUrl, just configure with QueueUrl in the first place.  No need to look it up every time.

Comment: I looked up the structure of the Queue URL (link below), and it looks like you are correct. Still curious as to why the GetQueueURL request doesn't respect timeouts, while other requests (like ReceiveMessage) do.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-queue-message-identifiers.html

Comment: That does seem strange.  I'd expect a DNS resolution failure right off the bat